# Yii2 update query with where in and not in condition

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

How can I write update query with where, in and not in condition.
I tried this one but it's not working properly. It updates all rows in a table. Not only working for mentioned rows but also all rows.

```
$postval=('2,4,5,7');
$netchk=TblNetwork::updateAll(['status' => 0],['AND', 
                'status = 1',  ['NOT IN', 'network_id_pk', $postval]
                ]);
```

Comment: Check out syntax for updateAll at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32477678/yii2-updateall-with-multi-conditions and https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#updateAll()-detail.

Comment: Your  update is condition is not clear  .. try add  the equivalent flat sql query so we can try to understand your goal

Answer (score 0):

You should use array of IDs for `NOT IN` condition (in you're example you're using string with list of IDs):

```
$postval = [2, 4, 5, 7];
$netchk = TblNetwork::updateAll(['status' => 0], [
        'AND', 
        'status = 1',  
        ['NOT IN', 'network_id_pk', $postval]
    ]);
```